# Is there a comparison between Scala and Google 'Go' language (feature by feature)?

Tags: scala, programming-languages, go, language-comparisons

I wonder if someone can produce a comparison between Scala and Google 'Go' language (feature by feature, like concurrency models, collections, etc.)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better compare it to **C** (or C++ or D).

As far as I do understand the intent of this language is to replace C/C++ **not** Java/Scala (VM languages). Go has no exceptions, assertions, inheritance. This is only bearable for C programmers.

I would like to see the new parts not present in other languages (or newly combined in Go). Especially how programs should be designed with the minimalistic type system.

Comment: They mentioned Java as a systems language in the tech talk.

Comment: I guess it's meant to be a better C++ alternative than Java.